# How to reference resource file in java maven project running in docker container

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, docker, zoho

I am trying to run a java maven (spring boot) project in a docker container to access the zoho api.

For authentication I need a file `zoho-oauthtokens.properties` which is located in src/main/resources and which I reference from another property file called `oauth_configuration.properties` like this:
`oauth_tokens_file_path=src/main/resources/zoho-oauthtokens.properties`

As long as I run the application in eclipse as spring application everything works fine but as soon as I run it in a docker container I get:
`com.zoho.crm.library.exception.ZCRMException com.zoho.oauth.common.ZohoOAuthException. Caused by : com.zoho.oauth.common.ZohoOAuthException. Caused by : java.io.FileNotFoundException: src/main/resources/zoho-oauthtokens.properties (No such file or directory)`

So how do I reference the resource file correctly that it will also be found when I run it i a docker container? Any idea?

I tried:

`oauth_tokens_file_path=src/main/resources/zoho-oauthtokens.properties`

`oauth_tokens_file_path=classpath:/zoho-oauthtokens.properties`

`oauth_tokens_file_path=/zoho-oauthtokens.properties`

`oauth_tokens_file_path=zoho-oauthtokens.properties`

and also after placing it in the root folder of my project:
`oauth_tokens_file_path=/zoho-oauthtokens.properties`

`oauth_tokens_file_path=zoho-oauthtokens.properties`

Best, Nils

EDIT:
It tried more options:

`../../../zoho-oauthtokens.properties`

`./zoho-oauthtokens.properties`

`/BOOT-INF/classes/zoho-oauthtokens.properties`

`BOOT-INF/classes/zoho-oauthtokens.properties`

Also I have inspected the jar file after the maven build. This is where the relevant files are located:

`BOOT-INF/classes/de/xxx/xxx/Application.class`

`BOOT-INF/classes/zoho-oauthtokens.properties`

`BOOT-INF/classes/oauth_configuration.properties`

Comment: Docker container have no filesysteme, so you might inject your file into your Docker instance during the Docker Start.

Comment: There are several resource files in src/main/resources which are used by the spring boot application. Those file are used without the need of specifying the path to the folder. So I am pretty sure it is possible to use property files without injecting them duriing docker start - I just don't know how to reference them.

Comment: The fact that `src/main/resources/zoho-oauthtokens.properties` works when running in Eclipse indicates that the code is not searching on the classpath because `src/main/resources` itself is not on the classpath. Do you have access to Zoho source code to see how the file path is loaded?

Comment: unfortunately I don't have access to the source code of the Zoho SDK...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
oauth_tokens_file_path=classpath*:zoho-oauthtokens.properties
```

Since it is in a different jar. Again I am not sure how zoho-oauthtokens.properties is loaded in code. Just worth a try.